# AddObserver UIKeyboardWillShowNotification trouble specifying object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to receive notification when the keyboard appears but I'm in a situation where I have 2 UITextViews and need to be able to differentiate between them. For some reason, I can't figure out how to filter this using the object parameter of "addObserver". I've got something like this:

```
 UITextView* w = mSubview.mText;
 NSNotificationCenter* dnc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
 [dnc addObserver:self selector:@selector(showNotesKeyboard:)  name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:w ];
```

Whenever I specify `w` I don't enter `showNotesKeyboard`. Only when I pass in `nil` does the notification actually get picked up. There must be something I'm missing here, please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add an observer to when the text view starts editing instead? Editing  will show keyboard.

```
UITextView* w = mSubview.mText;
[w addTarget:self action:@selector(showNotesKeyboard:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

Comment: This looks like it might work. I'll try it out tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Note for others: Yes, this works, and if the selector method is doing an animation, it will happen in conjunction with the keyboard slideup, same timing as the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification. Since the observer here is the textfield itself, it's the best choice if you want to isolate the notification to that field. Otherwise, if you want the selector called for *any* input field, use UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and see jbat100's answer.

Answer (score 1):

according to me it will get called only when it is nil cause it is a system generated notification , you can specify the object only when you created a custom notification for one of your classes. I mean when you yourself were posting this notification.

Answer (score 1):

This is the discussion for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification in the documentation

> Posted immediately prior to the display of the keyboard.
>
> **The notification object is nil.** The userInfo dictionary contains
>   information about the keyboard. Use the keys described in “Keyboard
>   Notification User Info Keys” to get the location and size of the
>   keyboard from the userInfo dictionary.

So you if you specify a sender object other than nil, you will not get any notifications. If you want to know which UITextView is active you can check which one is first responder.